# Prevent map jumping/swapping hozirontally using Google Map API's groundoverlay

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

All,
I am new to Google Map API. I am trying to display some images over Google Maps. I want to use `GroundOverlay` because it is easier to implement animation effects later in my work.

The problem is the image will jump horizontally between 'world-tiles' especially when I drag the map crossing -180 deg and 180 deg. Only part of the screen shows the image, which is annoying. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Error Screenshot]

Does anybody know how to prevent this? Actually I would like to replicate the behavior at:
http://forevermore.net/articles/photo-zoom/

I guess if I can limit the left and right boundaries of the map, then the image will not warp horizontally. But the example showing above is based on the `tile` overlay not `GroudOverlay`. Any ideas to implement the behavior using `GroundOverlay`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'center_changed',function() { checkBounds(); });

var allowedBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
     new google.maps.LatLng( , ),         //add your lat/long 
     new google.maps.LatLng( , )          //add your lat/long 
);

function checkBounds() {    
    if(! allowedBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) {
      var C = map.getCenter();
      var X = C.lng();
      var Y = C.lat();

      var maxX = allowedBounds.getNorthEast().lng();
      var maxY = allowedBounds.getNorthEast().lat();
      var minX = allowedBounds.getSouthWest().lng();
      var minY = allowedBounds.getSouthWest().lat();

      if (X < minX) {X = minX;}
      if (X > maxX) {X = maxX;}
      if (Y < minY) {Y = minY;}
      if (Y > maxY) {Y = maxY;}

      map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(Y,X));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Verma for your help. But this does not work. The image still wraps horizontally.